# what is the best way to display the output? (print,return)

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems that both `print` and `return` can display the output.

The only difference I found between is that `return` displays even quotation marks, whereas `print` doesn't.

How about using together?:

`return print("Hello")`

What is the most common and efficient way to display the output in a function(maybe the last line)?

Are there any changes to the flowchart between `return` and `print`?

Answer (score 2):

`return` certainly does not display output.  It *returns* output from a *function*.  If you happen to call a function in a python shell, you will get the output printed to the terminal, but this is incidental---it is because the python shell is a REPL: a Read Eval Print Loop.  So it *reads* what you type, *evaluates* it (i.e. runs it), and then *prints* whatever is left.

Thus `print` is for printing to stdout.  `return` is for getting values back from functions.

But I can see how one might get confused playing about in a REPL.

(Try just typing `return 7` in a python REPL to see why you *can't* use return as a print replacement, even in a REPL.)

Answer (score 1):

*return* - Returns a value so that it can be stored in a variable.

*print* - prints values to the stdout.

```
fu():
    x = 1
    print(x)

y = fu()
```

*y* is None

```
fu():
    x = 1
    return x
y = fu()
```

*y* is 1